# Como atribuir o valor escolhido em um select (HTML) para uma variável em php

Tags: php, html5

Eu tenho um código que preciso pegar o valor selecionado pelo usuário e o meu código pega sempre o ultimo código do select.

```
<?php
$tipo_info = 0;
echo "<fieldset>Selecione, qual o tipo da informação que deseja cadastrar.<br />";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
echo "<select>";
echo "<option></option>";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
  echo "<option name='ativo' value='".$reg["cod_tipo_info"]."'>".$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]."</option>";
  $tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br /><br />";

switch ($tipo_info){
  case 1:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 3:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 4:
    echo "<button type=\"submit\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Levando em consideração a resposta do @hugomg, e considerando que seu `select` já esteja dentro do form, há mais uma correção a fazer. Seu `select` está montado de maneira errada, o `name` deve ficar no `select` e não no `option`, exemplo:

```
<?php
$tipo_info = 0;
echo "<fieldset>Selecione, qual o tipo da informação que deseja cadastrar.<br />";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
echo "<select name='ativo'>"; //AQUI O NOME DO SELECT
echo "<option></option>";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
  echo "<option value='".$reg["cod_tipo_info"]."'>".$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]."</option>";
  $tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br /><br />";

switch ($tipo_info){
  case 1:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 3:
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
  case 4:
    echo "<button type=\"submit\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi, @abfurlan.
O seu código esta quase igual ao meu, com excessão do name no select.
Eu fiz essa alteração para manter o padrão e isso não mudou nada.
O grande problema é: `'$tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];`'
Se for fazer o teste de mesa ou o chines, ele vai percorrer o while e vai inclementar um, dois, três e fica com o resultado 4.
Talvez, eu tenha que criar um array list.
Alguém pode me ajudar?!?

Comment: @fabricio_wm, então o seu problema é outro e não pegar o valor selecionado no `select`, não está muito claro o problema, talvez seria interessante editar a pergunta e tentar ser mais específico

Comment: @fabricio_wm Se entendi, você quer que seja liberado para submeter o form somente se o usuário selecionar a opção com value 4 do select, é isso?

Comment: Sim.
Pq os demais button estão com type="button", ou seja, não fazem nada.
Só a opção 4 que vai dar um submit pq o type="submit".

Comment: Eu criei um formulário com PK na cabeça do formulario e dessa forma, o administrador do sistema vai poder inserir perguntas na quantidade que ela quiser e vai selecionar para a pergunta 1 a resposta pode ser do tipo select, Sim ou não (radio button) ou uma observação.
Entendeu?

Comment: Olhem isso:  <br/>
Não quero acabar com a programação existente aqui.
http://jsfiddle.net/U7Vvb/4/
Mas eu consegui outro jeito.
http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/kN84b/2/

Comment: @fabricio_wm, sim eu iria sugerir para fazer como javascript, mais aconselho você a tratar o valor do post no php.

Answer (score 1):

Na página HTML que você coinstruir, coloque o select dentro do um formulário HTML.

```
<form name="meuFormulario" action="umapagina.php" method="POST">
```

Quando o usuário subneter o formulário, o browser irá fazer uma requisição HTTP no endereço especificado pelo atributo `action`, usando o método POST. Até esse ponto funciona da mesma forma pra qualquer linguagem de programação web. Depois disso, o seu servidor irá receber essa requisição e irá executar o script PHP da página que o formulácio solicitou. Os dados do formulário estarão na variável `$_POST`, que é um hash que recebe o nome do elemento do formulário (que você especificou usando o atributo name) e devolve o valor que o usuário botou naquele campo.

Comment: Sim.
Ele esta dentro de um formulário.
Pensei que eu não precisasse copiar o código todo.
O código, só deve submeter se a pessoa escolher a opção 4 - Finalizar.
Obrigado.

Comment: Meu filho, eu não estou aqui pra fazer seu dever de casa. É impossível impedir o usuário de mandar dados incorretos (nunca confie nos dados que você recebe!) então o que você vai ter que fazer é ver se o usuário mandou a opção 4 e se ele não tiver mandado mandar o formulário denovo com uma mensagem dizendo que ele os dados dele estão inválidos. (Você até pode usar Javascript para fazer o browser impedir a submissão mas só é útil para performance, já que o cliente ainda tem formas de te mandar um formulário inválido se ele realmente quiser)

Comment: Eu não quero que ninguém faça o meu dever de casa. Acho que vc não entendeu a lógica.
Não existe opção errada. De acordo com a opção selecionada, ele vai ter um comportamento.
Acho que um forúm, é para aprendermos um com o outro de forma humilde.
Talvez, isso deve ser algo simples demais para você.
Se você retirar o código PHP, vc vai ver através do código http://jsfiddle.net/U7Vvb/4/ que nem todo button, faz submit.
Mas isso é comum, quando não analisamos o código ou substimamos as pessoas. 
Posso não ser bom em php, mas sei programar.

Comment: Desculpe, pensei que o finalizar era um comando pra mim, nao pro compudator. :-/  Desculpa de novo, fui mal educado mesmo.

Comment: Me desculpe tambem, @hugomg.
Tb fui rude. 
Não quero estresse ou problemas.
Fica com Deus.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possivel solução seria criar uma função que seleciona-se sempre o valor escolhido sempre que o form for submetido veja esse exemplo

```
function selected($value, $selected) {
    return $value == $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
}
```

Voce pode usar desse jeito

```html
<pre>
<select class="span6 m-wrap" name="genero">
          <option value="">-Seleciona um genero-</option>
          <option value="Masculino"
        <?php
       if (isset($valor) && !empty($valor)):
 echo selected($valor['genero'], "Masculino"); endif;?> >Masculino
</option>
        <option value="Femenino"
 <?php
     if (isset($valor) && !empty($valor)):
 echo selected($valor['genero'], "Femenino"); endif;?> >Femenino
</option>
  </select>  
</pre>
```

```
a variavael valor é onde vai estar guardado armazenado o teu Post ou seja
$valor=$_Post;
```

Veja esse Post [aqui](http://wbruno.com.br/php/mostrar-option-de-select-escolhido-pelo-usuario-php-mysql/)